# mysqldbcompare skip some tables

Tags: mysql

I need to compare 2 mysql databases. But i need to compare not all tables. Some tables must be skipped.

I wanted to use the tool mysqldbcompare . It looks what i need but i don't see an option to skip some tables. seems it will just compare all tables , which will not work for me (i know some tables are different, i want to skip them)

Is it possible to skip tables with this tool?

Maybe there is some alternative tool which can compare only selected tables?

In this manual there is nothing about tables skipping https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.5/en/mysqldbcompare.html

Comment: Did you find a solution? I also see nothing in the docs.

Comment: No, i didn't . I changed the logic of my tool, so, i had not need to do tables compare

Comment: awesome thanks for your answer. In our case its not crucial but I guess if there is heaps of data inside, that tool just would take longer. i also didn't find any option.